# TextBox Validation #2

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, passwords

I am currently working on a Windows form application. How can i create the Validation for my password textbox in visual studio (C#) that only allow the text which includes:

- At least one uppercase
- At least one lowercase
- At least one symbol
- Must be above 8 characters

Comment: Windows forms? Web forms? What?

Comment: I am working on a windows form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since its a Windows form application you can do the validation in code as:

```
string password = textBoxPassword.Text;
if (password.Length > 8 && // Must be above 8 characters
    password.Any(char.IsUpper) && //At least one uppercase
    password.Any(char.IsLower) && //At least one lowercase
    password.Any(char.IsSymbol) //At least one symbol
    )
{
    //Valid password
}
else
{
    //Invalid password
}
```

You can have this code against Submit button (Button_Click event), or TextBox TextChanging. You can extract it to a method like:

```
private bool IsValidPassword(string password)
{
    return (password.Length > 8 &&
        password.Any(char.IsUpper) &&
        password.Any(char.IsLower) &&
        password.Any(char.IsSymbol)
        );
}
```

For example if you want to validate the text on Button_Click then:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsValidPassword(textboxPassword.Text))
    {
        //valid password
    }
    else
    {
        //invalid password

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

if you want a digit in the password then you can add one extra check like:

```
password.Any(char.IsDigit)
```

To Check for `"!@#"` Add a check .

```
password.Any(char.IsPunctuation)
```

Comment: Why not show him how to use the appropriate event for validation? TextChanging or whatever.

Comment: why doesn't "!@#" is counted as a symbol? How can i make it as a symbol?

Comment: @Derek, they are not symbols,  see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00k2wda1.aspx, `Valid symbols are members of the following categories in UnicodeCategory: MathSymbol, CurrencySymbol, ModifierSymbol, and OtherSymbol.`.

Comment: @Derek, you can add a check if its a Punctuation `password.Any(char.IsPunctuation)`

Comment: Still it is not able to detect !@#, punctuation are ",." according to what i tried.. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**this is how it done:**

- Must be 8 Characters Long: You do not need a regex for this. Using
  the .Length property should be enough.
- Including 1 Uppercase letter: You can use the [A-Z]+ regular
  expression. If the string contains at least one upper case letter,
  this regular expression will yield true.
- 1 Special Character: You can use either the \W which will match any
  character which is not a letter or a number or else, you can use
  something like so [!@#] to specify a custom list of special
  characters. Note though that characters such as $, ^, ( and ) are
  special characters in regular expression language, so they need to be
  escaped like so: \$. So in short, you might use the \W.
- Alphanumeric Characters: Using the \w+ should match any letter and
  number and underscore.

Take a look at this tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex if its web-(Pls mention in question)

```
(                   # Start of group
    (?=.*\d)        #   must contain at least one digit
    (?=.*[A-Z])     #   must contain at least one uppercase character
    (?=.*\W)        #   must contain at least one special symbol
       .            #     match anything with previous condition checking
         {8,8}      #        length at least 8 characters and also maximum of 8
)                   # End of group
```

In one line:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,8})
```

### Sources:

- [Password matching expression](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/)
- [Password Strength Validation with Regular Expressions](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/)